# storing a column within another variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store a variable name firstRng into

```
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A"& lMaxRows + 1).Select
```

in place of "A"

here is what I have tried

```
Dim entireRange As Range
Dim firstRng As Range
Dim secondRng As Range

Set entireRange = Range("A2:C2")
Set secondRng = Range("B2")
Set firstRng = range("A:A")

    entireRange.Select
    secondRng.Activate
    Selection.Copy
    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, firstRng).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(firstRng & lMaxRows + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

it will error on 1maxRows "Type mismatch"

Comment: `firstRng.Cells(lMaxRows + 1)`.

Comment: `Set secondRng = Range("2")` - that's not valid.

Comment: When using `firstRng` use `Cells` and not `Range` and use `firstRng.Column` to return the column number: `lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, firstRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row`  And `Cells(lMaxRows , firstRng).Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstRng` is a multi-cell `Range`. You're implicitly working with its `.Value`, and not with relevant properties such as its `.Column`.

You should also avoid `Activate` and `Select`:

```
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, firstRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

entireRange.Copy Destination:= firstRng.Cells(lMaxRows + 1)
```

Or

```
entireRange.Copy Destination:= Cells(lMaxRows + 1, firstRng.Column)
```